# PHP 5.2, Ubuntu 10.04 Truncates External Input Variables

Tags: php, ubuntu, ubuntu-10.04, php-5.2

Why does PHP 5.2 on Ubuntu 10.04 LTS truncate long `$_POST` (external input) values, like the `max_input_vars` directive does in PHP 5.3?

I am supporting an old e-commerce site (that is soon to be replaced) and after recently updating, the admin could no longer fully edit a product due to the having over 1000 input vars.

(PHP 5.2 was installed using the [Zend Server Community Edition](http://www.zend.com/en/products/server-ce/))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I searched and debugged for quite a while to find out that is was the `max_input_vars` directive.  But, officially, there is no `max_input_vars` directive in PHP 5.2, according to [this](http://www.php.net/manual/en/info.configuration.php).

I finally found that it was back-ported [here](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/php5/5.2.4-2ubuntu5.22).

Updating/adding the directive solved the problem.

I hope this helps save someone else the headache of tracking this down.